# Insert into Hive table with specific parition

Tags: hadoop, hive

Forgive me for this dumb question i have google it and search for stack overflow
and it supposed to work

**I get an error for trying to load data into hive partitioned table**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE baba2 ( name string, age INT) PARTITIONED BY ( YEAR int) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE 
LOCATION '/user/hive/baba2/'
```

**create this simple file**

```
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ head babafile.txt
aaaaa,10
"bbbb",30
```

**Created a partition**

```
 ALTER TABLE BABA2 ADD PARTITION (YEAR=2015) LOCATION '/user/hive/baba2/2015';
```

After running this command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/cloudera/babafile.txt'
INTO TABLE BABA2 PARITION(YEAR=2015);
```

**I get this error :**

```
**parseexception line 2:17 missing eof at 'paritioned' near 'baba2'**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Load query 'partition' spelling is mismatch and else is fine.I ran same with correct code and it gives output.

> LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH './babafile.txt'
>   INTO TABLE BABA2 PARTITION(YEAR=2015);

Comment: Thanks can't figure it alone.